# Issue with odd and even rows with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have situation where I have structure like:

```
<table>
<tr class="chk"></tr>
<tr>one<tr>
<tr>two<tr>
<tr>three<tr>
<tr>four<tr>
<tr class="chk"></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr class="chk"></tr>
<tr>one<tr>
<tr>two<tr>
<tr>three<tr>
<tr>four<tr>
<tr class="chk"></tr>
</table>
```

Now what I want to do is to do something when tr chk is clicked.
What I am doing right now is:

```
$(".chk:even").click(function(){
    //do something
});


$(".chk:odd").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

**Note:** The above **is working** as I want.

I was wondering how I can determine if row is even or odd in a single function like:

```
$(".chk").click(function(){
  if(row is even){
     //do something
   }
  else{
    //do something
  }
});
```

Or is what I already have better or fine than the new version I am seeking?

Let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: it's faster to do      $(".chk").filter(":even")

Comment: The version you have is more "optimal" in that it will run the query once at page setup and attach the click handlers.  After that each time they are clicked it will just execute a function without any conditionals.  The way you are seeking will cause a query to run on every click.  Whether or not that matters depends on your application.

Comment: @Mike: I would stick to what I have if this is better than what I am seeking. My thinking is if there was already an calculated number assigned, I can use it because $(".chk:even") and $(".chk:odd") would be iterating through all rows twice correct?

Comment: @gbs: Performance is not always the most important consideration.  It depends a lot on your application.  If you are running almost the same code in both of your click handlers, it would be nice to be able to unify that logic into one place; that might make the second way better.  You trade performance for maintainability.  Of course, you could always just factor that logic down into a helper function instead.  In most cases I think my preference would be the solution you already have, possibly with a helper function(s).

Comment: Yes, they would iterate through the rows twice.  But that would be done at page load time, probably.  The way you seek would iterate only once at startup, but then you need to re-instantiate the 'this' object into a jquery object in order to use any utility functions to determine if it is even or not.  Allocating a new object is generally more expensive than iterating over a reasonably sized set.

Comment: @Mike: The logic is different i.e. when clicking top chk row(even) in a table, it search downwards until next chk row and upon bottom chk(odd) it iterates until top row. Also I get your point completely about re-iterating with new approach. Can you post your above comments as answer so I can give you credits for this.

Comment: @gbs: Done.  Answer at bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you have is more "optimal" in that it will run the query once at page setup and attach the click handlers. After that each time the elements are clicked it will just execute a function without any conditionals. The way you are seeking will cause a query to run on every click. Whether or not that matters depends on your application.

You're original way will iterate through the rows twice, true, but that will be done at page load time. The way you seek would iterate only once at startup, but then inside the click handler you need to wrap the 'this' object in a jQuery object every time it runs to determine if it's ":even".

Allocating a new object is generally more expensive than iterating over a reasonably sized set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".chk").click(function(){   
    var bIsEven = ($(this).index(".chk") % 2 == 0)?true:false;
    if(bIsEven){      
        //do something    
    }   else{     
        //do something   
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3h23G/6/

Comment: I don;t think it is returning the index as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/3h23G/5/

Comment: Thanks Cybernate. The update version gives the correct index. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".chk").click(function(){ 
    var evens = $(".chk:even");
    if (jQuery.contains( evens, row )){      
            //do something    
        }   else{     
            //do something   
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chks = $("tr.chk"); 

for(var i=0;i<chks.length;i++) {
    // even 
    if(i % 2 == 0) {

    }
    else {  // odd

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/99bjW/)):

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    var row = $(this),
        color = (row.index() % 2) ? 'red' : 'blue';
    row.css('background', color);
});
```

it's odd the the `.is(':even')` and `.is(':odd')` isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Well if nothing else works, you can use .index(); to get the 0-based index and then use % 2.